# How can I convert my xtext project into client server architecture

Tags: xtext, codemirror

I am working with eclipse. I want to convert my xtext project into client server based project where all runtime resources will act as clients and my main xtext project will act as server.
How can I achieve that? I have read about xtext web APIs like codemirror and ace but cannot seem to find proper documentation on how to convert my project using them.

Comment: please check the new project wizard. simplest would be start new project and copy your stuff over. more complicated vice versa

Comment: I used DLSForge but as soon as I get to the part of setting target platform, it starts giving me errors in all projects in workspace. Seems like it has forgotten xtext somehow.

Comment: xtext web works with maven and gradle only. no support for eclipse plugins. therefore you would have a look at language servers, lsp4e, lsp4j (see docs)